# Is not a function error on template syntax using with strings

Tags: javascript, templates, ecmascript-6, syntax, syntax-error

i've been noticed about this error on js es6 template syntax

When you type an string and after it just type template syntax, javascript automatically transforms first string into a Method

Here you have an stackblitz link to tryout
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ty94oe

```js
const testTemplateSyntax = 'test' `hello`;
```

Probably i expected Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

But i've got test is not a function

**EDIT**

Error is caused because on tepmlate [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)

But test is not defined in any context and cant find this method.

Comment: And whats your question? It is still invalid syntax, although it gets interpreted as a *tagged template literal* ?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an expression *immediately before* a backtick, the only way the interpreter can parse it is if you're using a tagged template literal, and the expression is a function. For example:

```js
const testTemplateSyntax = (() => '')`hello`;
console.log(testTemplateSyntax, typeof testTemplateSyntax);

const testTemplateSyntax2 = function(){ return '' }`hello`;
console.log(testTemplateSyntax2, typeof testTemplateSyntax2);
```

It's kind of like an IIFE for a tagged template. If the expression on the left can't be evaluated as a function, then it will throw the error you see.

Any other non-function expression on the left will result in the same runtime error:

```js
5 `foo`
```

```js
null `foo`
```

```js
undefined `foo`
```

```js
({}) `foo`
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) which allows to parse template literals with a function

Comment: Thanks dude, this is what i needed.